# Can we limit what shows up in the first page of your feed, based on relevance?

Tags: discussion, support

This question from 2010 just showed on the first page of my feed:

[Why are my html buttons moving in I.E? They don't move in Chrome or FF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493838/why-are-my-html-buttons-moving-in-i-e-they-dont-move-in-chrome-or-ff)

It showed because someone changed the `table` tag to `html-table`.

The tag change is the right thing to do but the question has an accepted answer, also from 2010, and I can't see the benefit of broadcasting it onto the front page of a feed, again?

I'm guessing it just happens because the post had activity. Surely there's a need to assess the activity and bump (or not) the post accordingly.

I see this quite a lot with edits from years ago to questions with accepted answers and struggle to see why they are there?